# onclick event worling with id not working with class

Tags: javascript

While this works:

```
var lnk = document.getElementById("lnk");

lnk.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

it no longer works with class and getElementsByClassName

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. You have to access them by index or in a for loop to attach the click handler to each one

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a `nodeList` which is array like.

So you would have to bind the event to each `node` in the list.

```
var lnks = document.getElementsByClassName("lnk");
                    or
var lnks = document.querySelectorAll(".lnk");

lnks.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

Comment: working! Thank you!